# Partial derivatives and continuity of function in two variable

Tags: calculus, partial-derivative

Can we use the increment theorem for proving that functions with bounded partial derivatives is continuous ?

(There is one question similar to this asked in 2013.But I want to know what is wrong with this proof)

$\delta z= f_{x}\delta x+f_{y}\delta y+\epsilon_{1}\delta x+\epsilon_{2}\delta y$ where $\epsilon_{1} $ $\epsilon_{2}$ tends to $0 $ as $\delta x,\delta y$ tends to $0$
But $\delta z =f(x+\delta x,y+\delta y)-f(x,y)$ Applying boundedness of partial derivatives $f_{x} $and  $ f_{y}$ we get as $limit f(x+\delta x,y+\delta y)=f(x,y) $ as $\delta x,\delta y$ tends to $0$.

Answer (score 1):

You do not know $f$ is differentiable just because it has partial derivatives. Of course, differentiability always implies continuity.

**EDIT:** To clarify, your stipulation that $\epsilon_i\to 0$ requires that $f$ be differentiable. We don't have that.

Comment: Can we say that ? There are functions whose partial derivatives exist but functions are discontinuous.

Comment: Right. Those functions are not differentiable!